# How can I read a file with Selenium Chrome Driver without needing filesystem?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I currently do as following to download a file and read it's contents to a `byte[]`:

```
Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<>();
preferences.put("download.default_directory", "/tmp");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);

options.addArguments(
    "--headless=new",
    "--disable-gpu",
    "--no-sandbox");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get(url);

Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
    .withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(60000L))
    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(1000L));

File file = wait.until(webDriver -> {

    try {
        File[] files = new File("/tmp").listFiles();
        for (File candidate : files)
            if (candidate.getPath().equalsIgnoreCase("MyFile.txt")) return candidate;
    } catch (Throwable exception) {
        /* Intentionally left blank */
    }

    return null;
});

byte[] buffer = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

It works fine, except that it needs filesystem to download the file into (`"/tmp"`) and read it from there. Can it be done so that no filesystem is needed and everything is done in memory?

Comment: You can't do much at all without a filesystem.  Can you describe your use-case?

Comment: The VM is monitored for filesystem changes (file creation etc.) for security purposes and the client doesn’t want to create files.

Comment: you could possibly execute script to create an objectURL in the browser... not real sure where the browser stores those, but it may be in a file that already exists: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static